# Deserialize JSON Facebook feed using Gson

Tags: android, json, gson

I have a JSON response from Facebook with the following structure:

```
{
    "data": [
      {
         "id": "105458566194298_411506355589516",
         "message": "...",
         "type": "status",
         "created_time": "2012-11-25T17:26:41+0000",
         "updated_time": "2012-11-25T17:26:41+0000",
         "comments": {
            "count": 0
      },
      {
         "id": "105458566194298_411506355589516",
         "message": "...",
         "type": "status",
         "created_time": "2012-11-25T17:26:41+0000",
         "updated_time": "2012-11-25T17:26:41+0000",
         "comments": {
            "count": 0
      }
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to deserialize it using the Gson library:

```
public class FacebookPost {
    public String Message;
    public String Created_time;
}
```

---

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<FacebookPost>>() {}.getType();

ArrayList<FacebookPost> userList = gson.fromJson(responseJsonString, listType);
```

This would obviosuly just work if the response wasn't wrapper in the `"data": [ ]` - container. But how do I tell gson to look inside `data` in the JSON response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do something like that:

```
InputStream source = retrieveStream(url);
Gson gson = new Gson();
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(source);
APIResponse response = gson.fromJson(reader, APIResponse.class);
```

With:

```
Public class APIResponse{

    ArrayList <FacebookPost> data;

    public class FacebookPost {
        public String message;
        public String created_time;
    }
}
```