# Deserialize a json container array

Tags: c#, arrays, json.net, containers, json-deserialization

The data I am trying to Deserialize is exacly like this json in this post>

[Deserialize JSON Facebook feed using Gson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13553584/deserialize-json-facebook-feed-using-gson) , Only with more objects, inside the container.. and i'm not using "Gson"

I think some of the objects even have their own containers nested somewhere, but that is not the issue at present, the main issue is that I am having problems deserializing into the following class..

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public int found { get; set; }
    public Post[] posts { get; set; }
    public Meta meta { get; set; }
}
```

I understand that the way the json from the API is layed out, it some sort of array, in the Json.net docs, they call it a DataSet.. I am using Json.Net

my most recent attempt to deserialize is;

```
List<Rootobject> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Rootobject>>(stringData);
```

But still data is null and I get;

Additional information:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})
>   into type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[WebApplication17.Models.Rootobject]'
>   because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize
>   correctly.

perhaps LINQ to JSON is the way to go not sure as yet.. any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing is the JSON at the post is not a valid JSON string so it cannot be desearlized. Secondly I tried to rectify and correct the JSON to make it a valid JSON and thus your JSON looks like

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "105458566194298_411506355589516",
            "message": "...",
            "type": "status",
            "created_time": "2012-11-25T17:26:41+0000",
            "updated_time": "2012-11-25T17:26:41+0000",
            "comments": {
                "count": 0
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "105458566194298_411506355589516",
            "message": "...",
            "type": "status",
            "created_time": "2012-11-25T17:26:41+0000",
            "updated_time": "2012-11-25T17:26:41+0000",
            "comments": {
                "count": 0
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

So the Classes structure would be something like this

```
public class Comments
{
    public int count { get; set; }
}
public class Datum
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public DateTime created_time { get; set; }
    public DateTime updated_time { get; set; }
    public Comments comments { get; set; }
}
public class MyData
{
    public List<Datum> data { get; set; }
}
```

and then Desearlize it normally like you were doing

```
MyData data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyData>(stringData);
```

Comment: Makes sense.. what you have done by amending the anti-pattern Json.
My code is more like this, the difference being "found". 

{
"found": 12, 
"posts": [
{},
{}
]
}
    public class Rootobject
{
   public int found { get; set; }
   public Post[] posts { get; set; }
   public List<Post> data { get; set; }
   public Meta meta { get; set; }
    }
Rootobject data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(stringData);

I can not alter the Json as it is from Wordpress public API ... In any event, I took your advice and I'm pretty sure it has done the job so nice one mate.